# How do you map a shared CD/DVD drive on the host to a drive letter on the Gues in Windows Virtual PC?

Tags: windows-7, windows-virtual-pc

In the previous versions of Virtual PC, the Host's CD/DVD drives just get assigned drive letters. Nice and neat.

But in Windows Virtual PC (Win 7) the drives are all just available but without drive letters. I need to access the Host's CD drive using a drive letter.

Comment: Questions like this should be posted on SuperUser since it's not programming related... Having the answer within 1 minute after posting also suggests you're typing before thinking...

Comment: The creators of SO have often discussed that no question is too basic and that SO is even a good place to save an answer you figured out, for future reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out:

You can go into Tools > Settings > DVD Drive
Then in the properties you can assign that drive (on the Guest O/S) to a folder, drive, etc.

It defaulted (rather ignorantly :-(  to the Host's D: drive, which isn't a CD drive at all so it looked like it was broken.